# How to generate auto swagger API doc (yaml) format based on schema or based on database structure?

Tags: node.js, api, express, swagger

Is there any way to auto generate a **swagger API** docs based on my schema or database structure, that instead of manually typing get, put, delete, post and all those stuff in yaml which is the swagger API docs it will just be auto generated. 
Thanks, you can ask me anything like regarding o creating the scaffold and stuffs.

api doc (yaml format)

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: practice
  description: practice yo scuffolding
basePath: /api/v1
tags:
  - name: Examples
    description: Simple example endpoints
  - name: Person
    description: Simple person endpoints
  - name: Account
    description: Simple person endpoints
  - name: Specification
    description: The swagger API specification

consumes:
  - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  - application/form-data
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

definitions:
  ExampleBody:
    type: object
    title: example
    required:
      - name
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: The example name
  PersonBodyUpdate:
    type: object
    title: person
    required:
      oneOf:
        - Name
        - Position
        - Gender
    properties:
      Name:
        type: string
        description: The Person name
      Position:
        type: string
        description: The Person position
      Gender:
        type: string
        description: The Person gender
  PersonBodyPost:
    type: object
    title: person
    required: true
      - Name
      - Position
      - Gender
    properties:
      Name:
        type: string
        description: The Person name
      Position:
        type: string
        description: The Person position
      Gender:
        type: string
        description: The Person gender      
  AccountBody:
    type: object
    title: account
    required:
      - Username
      - Password
      - Person_id
    properties:
      Username:
        type: string
        description: The Account name
      Password:
        type: string
        description: The Account position
      Person_id:  
        type: integer
        description: The Account Person_id 
  LoginBody:
    type: object
    title: login
    required: true
      - Username
      - Password
    properties:
      Username:
        type: string
        description: The Account Username
      Password:
        type: string
        description: The Account Password                      
paths:
  /examples:
    get:
      tags:
        - Examples
      description: Fetch all examples
      responses:
        200:
          description: Returns all examples
    post:
      tags:
        - Examples
      description: Create a new example
      parameters:
        - name: example
          in: body
          description: number of items to skip
          required: true
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/ExampleBody"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Returns all examples

  /examples/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - Examples
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the entity to retrieve
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the example with the specified id
        404:
          description: Example not 

  /spec:
    get:
      tags:
        - Specification
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the API specification

  /person:
    get:
      tags:
        - Person
      description: Fetch all person
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
    post:
      tags:
        - Person 
      description: Create a new person
      parameters:
        - name: person
          in: body
          description: number of items to skip
          required: true
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/PersonBodyPost"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Create person

  /person/{id}:
    delete:
      tags:
        - Person
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the entity to be delete
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the products with the specified id
        404:
          description: Products not 4u2Dj7
    put:
      tags:
        - Person
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the entity to be delete
          type: integer
        - name: person
          in: body
          description: number of items to skip
          required: true
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/PersonBodyUpdate"  
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the products with the specified id
        404:
          description: Products not

  /account:
    get:
      tags:
        - Account
      description: Fetch all account
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
    post:
      tags:
        - Account 
      description: Create a new account
      parameters:
        - name: account
          in: body
          description: number of items to skip
          required: true
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/AccountBody"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Create account

  /account/{id}:
    delete:
      tags:
        - Account
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the entity to be delete
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the account with the specified id
        404:
          description: Products not 4u2Dj7
    put:
      tags:
        - Account
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the entity to be delete
          type: integer
        - name: account
          in: body
          description: number of items to skip
          required: true
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/AccountBody"  
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the account with the specified id
        404:
          description: Account not Found

  /account/login:
    get: 
      tags:
        - Account 
      description: login an account
      security:
        - basicAuth:[]  
      responses:
        200:
          description: Create account
```

schema :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('account', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    },
    Password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    },
    Person_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'person',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'account',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same question on Github and it got this answer:

"Try the loopback project from strongloop, it can connect to database tables and create models (exposed as swagger) from them."

Here I think is the Loopback link:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Swagger-generator.html

Let me know if it worked for you ;)